# How are variables inherited in PHP functions (globals/locals)?

Tags: php, scope, namespaces, global

My primary programming language is python, but I inherited a PHP project to maintain, and I am trying to fix some SQL injection vulnerabilities. I have one file that has me baffled. It is working, but I have no idea how. On line 14, it invokes `$db`, but I do not understand how `$db` is available within that function. It is defined in other php files within the project, but my understanding was that global variables have to be declared (as `$tbl_users` is) to be available inside a function. Where else do I need to look to know where `authValidateUser` is getting `$db` from?

```
<?php
$user_list_link = "edit_users.php";

function authValidateUser($user, $pass)
{
   global $tbl_users;

   $user = strtolower($user);
   $pass = md5($pass);

   $user = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9.]+/i","",$user);
   $pass = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9.]+/i","",$pass);

   return sql_query1($db, "select count(*) from $tbl_users where name = '$user' and password = '$pass';");
}

function authGetUserLevel($user, $lev1_admin)
{
   // User not logged in, user level '0'
   if(!isset($user))
      return 0;

   // Check if the user is can modify
   for($i = 0; isset($lev1_admin[$i]); $i++)
   {
      if(strcasecmp($user, $lev1_admin[$i]) == 0)
     return 2;
   }

   // Everybody else is access level '1'
   return 1;
}
?>
```

`sql_query1` is the following:

```
function sql_query1 ($db, $sql)
{
        $r = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        if (! $r) return -1;
        if (mysqli_num_rows($r) != 1 || mysqli_num_fields($r) != 1
                || ($result = mysqli_result($r, 0, 0)) == "") $result = -1;
        mysqli_free_result($r);
        return $result;
}
```

Comment: `$db` will be null inside that function - nothing happening elsewhere can affect this. Whether this code actually *works* or not will depend on what `sql_query1()` does if the first argument is null, but either way PHP will raise a notice about an undefined variable.

Comment: Only way this is not throwing a notice that I can think of is that your server has the [runkit extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/runkit.installation.php) installed and has registered a superglobal named `$db` [custom_superglobals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/runkit.configuration.php#ini.runkit.superglobal)

Comment: @iainn I added `sql_query1` to the question.

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou How can I check to see whether that is the case?

Comment: You have to check if there is something like `runkit.superglobal=db`. Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3).